# Cannot Run Openshift Jboss EAP 7 with Mysql Persistent using default parameters

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, openshift

Everytime i create new JBoss EAP7 with MySQL Persistent Type Applications, i'm always receiving Error Deployment Failed for the MySQL Pod. the log says like this

```
--> Scaling xxx-mysql-2 to 1
--> Waiting up to 10m0s for pods in deployment xxx-mysql-2 to become ready
W0326 15:34:23.420524       1 reflector.go:330] github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/deploy/strategy/support/lifecycle.go:468:
watch of *api.Pod ended with: too old resource version: 1042923611 (1042946447)
 error: update acceptor rejected xxx-mysql-2: pods for deployment "xxx-mysql-2" took longer than 600 seconds to become ready
```

Is this openshift bugs or Perhaps i have made mistakes?

Comment: Post the log from your pod, this is from the deployment.

Comment: @jklee i cannot get the log from the pods,  it always says "loading logs..."  and it just waiting for the container creating... perhaps you can try yourself

Comment: Any Events from your pod? OpenShift Preview or Origin?